# How to read variable value from HTML page using JAVA

Tags: javascript, java

I am trying to automate our company mail (gmail) login and use via JAVA. I am using HttpURLConnection for that. I am able to get all login inputs except one which is cookie generated directly by Html page JavaScript function. I am providing most important part of Html code. What I really need is to read value of 'end' and 'start' variables (suppose cookie value equals to difference of those).

To be honest I am completely lost. I can parse all values which are displayed directly in code but no experience with JavaScript functions calls from JAVA. Could you help to provide advice/"example" of that how to process that?

Tom

```
<script type=text/javascript>
<!--

.
.
.

function GetRoundtripTimeFunction(start)
 {
  return function()
 {
  var end = (new Date()).getTime();
  SetGmailCookie("GMAIL_RTT", (end - start));
 }
 }
.
.
. 
</script>
```

Comment: What exactly are you asking? How to call a JavaScript function from Java? How to read cookies? How to use GMAIL API from Java? And what exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I want to know how to call JavaScript function which is put in some HTML page code from JAVA. And how to read variables values which are defined by function on HTML page.